# Showing $n^3 = \Omega ((n+7)^3)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, asymptotics

> Prove/Disprove: $n^3 = \Omega ((n+7)^3)$

Pretty sure it's correct since both sides have the same degree, so if we replace all the degrees 1 and 2 expressions from the RHS with $n^3$, we get $((n+7)^3) \le 170n^3$.

So we get that $n^3 \ge \frac 1 {170} ((n+7)^3)$ for $n_0=1$ therefore  $n^3 = \Omega ((n+7)^3)$

Was that alright?

Comment: Sure. Another way would be to note that for $n \geq 7$, $n+7 \leq 2n$, so for $n \geq 7$, $(n+7)^3 \leq 8n^3$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I was certain there's an easier way then to expand the $(n+7)^3$